# how to make an if statement in switch case by not get the value of the another case?

Tags: java, algorithm, switch-statement

right now i have a problem that i want to run my code with this
i make to check februay on the case 2 if year is true than run the execute if statement if it was false it will go to default but right now it go to the case 3 statement how to solve that not go to the case 3 but go to the default?

//this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getDaysInMonth(1, 2018);
    System.out.println(getDaysInMonth(2, 2018));

}

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if(year < 1 && year > 9999) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if(year % 4 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if(year % 100 == 0) {
            return false;
        } else if(year % 400 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }         
}

public static int getDaysInMonth(int month, int year) {
    if((month < 1 || month > 12) && (year < 1 || year > 9999)) {
        return -1;
    }
    isLeapYear(year);
    int days;
    switch(month) {
        case 1:
            days = 31;
            break;
        case 2:
            if(year == 1) {
                days = 29;
                break;
            } 

        case 3:
            days = 31;
            break;
        case 4:
            days = 30;
            break;
        case 5:
            days = 31;
            break;
        case 6:
            days = 30;
            break;
        case 7:
            days = 31;
            break;
        case 8:
            days = 31;
            break;
        case 9:
            days = 30;
            break;
        case 10:
            days = 31;
            break;
        case 11:
            days = 30;
            break;
        case 12:
            days = 31;
            break;                
        default:
            days = 28;
            break;             
    }
      return days; 
}
```

Comment: As an aside, your `isLeapYear` returns a `boolean`, but you are forgetting to use the return value.

Comment: The isLeapYear function does not work properly. The else if statements are never reached. You need to reorder the if statements starting with %400 then %100 and finally %4.

Comment: why are you using such an uncommon occurrence as the default? I would expect the default to be 30 or 31. or better yet throw an error for invalid argument if you reach default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because your `break` is in the `IF` scope -> then if the year not 1 its continue to case 3.

You can use `if else` clause:

```
    case 2:
        if(year == 1) {
            days = 29;
        } else {
            days = 28;
        }
        break;
```

But I have to remind you, `year != 1` does not mean its Feb get 28 days, maybe you want this:

```
    case 2:
        if(!isLeapYear(year)) {
            days = 29;
        } else {
            days = 28;
        }
        break;
```

Comment: wah i am so appriciated you help me its work i dont know that in the if statement use isLeapYear(year) i use == 1 i think it can my bad

Comment: oh if(method tht we call) it will go if the method is true right?

Comment: yes, and add a `!` ahead,  means *it will go if the method is false*.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the question about `if` statements and `switch`, there are some problems to be addressed with the method for leap year checking first. Here is the beginning of original code below:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if(year < 1 && year > 9999) {
        return false;
    } else {
        ...
```

The condition `year < 1 && year > 9999` can never happen since `year` can't be both less than one and greater than 9999 at the same time so it's redundant.

Other than this, the algorithm for determining if a year is a leap year is as follows (in plain English):

1. See if the year is evenly divisible by 4. If not, it can't be a leap year (return false).
2. Here a year is evenly divisible by 4 (determined in step 1). If it is not evenly divisible by 100, it is a leap year (return true).
3. Here a year is evenly divisible by 4 and also by 100. If the year is also evenly divisible by 400 then it is a leap year. Otherwise it isn't.

Putting all of the above considerations into code, it can be made more readable:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year % 4 != 0) {
        // year is not evenly divisible by 4 (it has a remainder, can't be a leap year). 
        return false;
    }
    // year is evenly divisible by 4
    if (year % 100 != 0) {
        // divisible by 4 and not 100, it's a leap year
        return true;
    }
    // divisible by 4 and also 100
    if (year % 400 != 0) {
        // divisible by 4, 100 and not by 400
        return false;
    }

    // divisible by 4, 100 and 400
    return true;
}
```

Considering your `getDaysInMonth` method, we have the following cases, with 1 = January, 2 = February and so on:

30 days: September (9), April (4), June (6), November (11)

31 days: All others but February (2) (28, 29 on a leap year)

```
public static int getDaysInMonth(int month, int year) {
    switch (month) {
        case 9:
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 11:
            return 30;
        case 2:
            if (isLeapYear(year)) {
                return 29;
            } else {
                return 28;
            }
        default:
            return 31;
    }
}
```

Regarding validation of arguments, if you are receiving user input, it should all be validated outside of the methods used for calculation (pass the methods input that's already been validated instead of validating directly inside them).